# Sharing axis ranges - Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to share the ranges of my `X-axis` so that when I pan through my plots all of them move together.

I am trying to follow the example from the [Guide Line](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#userguide-quickstart). But because I am plotting them in a different way it does not allow me to share the range.

```
p = [figure(title="Title", 
            x_axis_label='Time (secs)', 
            y_axis_label='Voltage (V)', 
            tools = TOOLS, 
            x_range=(0, 500), 
            y_range=(0, 1000)),

    figure(title="Title_1", 
           x_axis_label='Time (secs)', 
           y_axis_label='Voltage (V)',  
           tools = TOOLS,
           x_range=p[0].x_range, 
           y_range=(0, 500))]
```

I get the following:

```
   x_range=p[0].x_range,

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a list in which one of the elements refers to its first index.
You can't refer to an index of the element on the definition.

for example:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

list1 = ['first', Person(list1[0])]
```

and in your snippet code:

```py
p = [figure(title="Title", 
            x_axis_label='Time (secs)', 
            y_axis_label='Voltage (V)', 
            tools = TOOLS, 
            x_range=(0, 500), 
            y_range=(0, 1000)),

    figure(title="Title_1", 
           x_axis_label='Time (secs)', 
           y_axis_label='Voltage (V)',  
           tools = TOOLS,
           x_range=p[0].x_range, # Here is problem you the p[0] is refering 
                                 #  to index 0 on definition of the list 
           y_range=(0, 500))]
```

You can do something like below for the purpose you got:

```py
p = [
    figure(
        title="Title", 
        x_axis_label='Time (secs)', 
        y_axis_label='Voltage (V)', 
        tools = TOOLS, 
        x_range=(0, 500), 
        y_range=(0, 1000)
    )
]
p.append(
    figure(
       title="Title_1", 
       x_axis_label='Time (secs)', 
       y_axis_label='Voltage (V)',  
       tools = TOOLS,
       x_range=p[0].x_range,
       y_range=(0, 500)
    )
)
```

Comment: But then... How would I acces the x_range of the 1st figure? @shayan rok rok

Comment: @falo8056 Check out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the range after the creation instead of during creation:

```
p[1].x_range = p[0].x_range
```